# Form not showing with {% csrf_token %} {{ cart_product_form }} Django

Tags: python, html, django, forms

So I am trying to show a dropdown menu with Django 2.x (latest version) for an ecommerce site that allows you to select the quantity of an item before adding to cart but the quantity form is not showing. I have a shop app and a cart app and the form is in the cart app. Here is what it looks like:

[image: No quantity drop down menu is showing]

How do I get it to show?

**html**

```
<form action="{% url "cart:cart_add" product.id %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ cart_product_form }}
    <input type="submit" value="add to cart" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
```

Here is what the dev tools looks like:
 [Dev Tools for the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MR98W.png)

**shop views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Category, Product
from cart.forms import CartAddProductForm
from django.template import RequestContext

def product_list(request, category_slug=None):
    category = None
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    products = Product.objects.filter(available=True)
    if category_slug:
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
        products = Product.objects.filter(category=category)

    context = {
        'category': category,
        'categories': categories,
        'products': products
    }
    return render(request, 'shop/product/list.html', context)


def product_detail(request, id, slug):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=id, slug=slug, available=True)
    cart_product_form = CartAddProductForm()
    context = {
        'product': product,
        'cart_product_form': cart_product_form
    }
    return render(request, 'shop/product/detail.html', context)
```

**shop urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import re_path
from . import views

app_name = 'shop'

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^$', views.product_list, name='product_list'),
    re_path(r'^(?P<category_slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.product_list, name='product_list_by_category'),
    re_path(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.product_detail, name='product_detail'),
]
```

**cart forms.py**

```
from django import forms

PRODUCT_QUANTITY_CHOICES = [(i, str(i)) for i in range(1, 26)]

class CartAddProductForm(forms.Form):
    quantity = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=PRODUCT_QUANTITY_CHOICES, coerce=int)
    update = forms.BooleanField(required=False, initial=False, widget=forms.HiddenInput)
```

**cart cart.py**

```
from decimal import Decimal
from django.conf import settings
from shop.models import Product


class Cart(object):
    def __init__(self, request):
        self.session = request.session
        cart = self.session.get(settings.CART_SESSION_ID)
        if not cart:
            cart = self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID] = {}
        self.cart = cart

    def add(self, product, quantity=1, update_quantity=False):
        product_id = str(product.id)
        if product_id not in self.cart:
            self.cart[product_id] = {'quantity': 0, 'price': str(product.price)}
        if update_quantity:
            self.cart[product_id]['quantity'] = quantity
        else:
            self.cart[product_id]['quantity'] += quantity
        self.save()

    def save(self):
        self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID] = self.cart
        self.session.modified = True

    def remove(self, product):
        product_id = str(product.id)
        if product_id in self.cart:
            del self.cart[product_id]
            self.save()

    def __iter__(self):
        product_ids = self.cart.keys()
        products = Product.objects.filter(id__in=product_ids)
        for product in products:
            self.cart[str(product.id)]['product'] = product

        for item in self.cart.values():
            item['price'] = Decimal(item['price'])
            item['total_price'] = item['price'] * item['quantity']
            yield item

    def __len__(self):
        return sum(item['quantity'] for item in self.cart.values())

    def get_total_price(self):
        return sum(Decimal(item['price']) * item['quantity'] for item in self.cart.values())

    def clear(self):
        del self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID]
        self.session.modified = True
```

**cart views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST
from shop.models import Product
from .cart import Cart
from .forms import CartAddProductForm


@require_POST
def cart_add(request, product_id):
    cart = Cart(request)
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    form = CartAddProductForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        cart.add(product=product, quantity=cd['quantity'], update_quantity=cd['update'])
    return redirect('cart:cart_detail')


def cart_remove(request, product_id):
    cart = Cart(request)
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    cart.remove(product)
    return redirect('cart:cart_detail')


def cart_detail(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    for item in cart:
        item['update_quantity_form'] = CartAddProductForm(initial={'quantity': item['quantity'], 'update': True})
    return render(request, 'cart/detail.html', {'cart': cart})
```

Comment: Have a try after enclosing {{cart_product_form}} inside a table tag.

Comment: The code looks solid to me. Did you inspect the form in `devtools`? what did you find?

Comment: putting cart_product_form in a table get's rid of the text "Quantity: " and the list still doesnt show.

Comment: I just edited the post and added a pic of what the dev tools looks like for the form